# Save image (from javascript) in a public folder (through php)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to use this package
https://vuejsexamples.com/a-beautiful-vue-component-for-image-cropping-and-uploading/
But then I am wondering how to save my image in a folder.

I am trying to do this in php so that I can use easily the route afterwards, but it could be OK with JS as well if it is easier.

```
public function uploadfile(Request $request){
    $img = $request->img;
    $newlocation = $request->newlocation;
    $filename = $request->filename;

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $request->img); //I tried with and without this

    return file_put_contents ($newlocation . "/" . $filename , $img );
}
```

I actually get an image in my public folder but the content is absolutely not what I want :)
The image.jpg contains the text C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\phpEE72.tmp

Comment: when you say the image content is not what you want, and contains the text C:\x\x are you saying displaying when you display the image it just reads that text as opposed to the uploaded image?

Comment: Hi, if I open the file with vscode it contains the text "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\phpEE72.tmp"

Answer (score 1):

I found this link very helpful when uploading images:
https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-57-image-upload-with-validation-example

In my controller I have something like this after validation, which allows for different image filetypes like png and jpg:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$getimageName = $name.'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->image->move(public_path('filelocation'), $getimageName);
```

And in my filesystems.php file:

```
'disks' = > [
    'filelocation' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/foldername',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/foldername',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the string of the filename. Behind the scenes PHP handles all files uploaded to the server by putting in a temp directory. It's up to you to move it and process it. All you'd need to do is to read the file's contents first:

```
file_put_contents ($newlocation . "/" . $filename , file_get_contents($img) )
```

without your str_replace.

You should consider doing this in a more Laravel way as recommended in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads but to answer the immediate question, all you need if file_get_contents.